# php script to increment values of cell associated with name?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Making a game that asks the user to choose between two words. One is "correct" and the other is "incorrect." If the user chooses the wrong word, I'd like that wrong word to get a +1 on it's neighboring column. This would be saved to the server in a simple file, maybe CSV, so that everyone's data gets recorded in that way. It would end up looking like this:

```
word1  124
word2  80
word3  14
```

Also, if the word doesn't already have a spot in the list it would ideally be added. I'm a front-end person, but this seems simple-ish. I'm hoping I can simply modify a similar script. I'd love if this was possible with javascript, or if google spreadsheets were easy to work with remotely!

EDIT:
It's important that this info is collected in a single server-side file/table. This is so I can monitor how tricky each word is. So that I know that word1 was chosen much more than word3, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var correct_word = "thisiscorrect";

    function do_guess() {
        if ($("#guess").val() != correct_word) {
            $.ajax("log.php", {
                data:{
                    word:$("#guess").val()
                }
            });
            if ($("tr[word='" + $("#guess").val() + "']").length == 0) {
                $("#words_history").append("<tr word='" + $("#guess").val() + "'><td>" + $("#guess").val() + "</td><td>1</td></tr>");
            }
            else {
                $("tr[word='" + $("#guess").val() + "'] td:eq(1)").html(parseInt($("tr[word='" + $("#guess").val() + "'] td:eq(1)").html())+1);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("SUCCESS!");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="words_history">
    </table>

    <input type="text" id="guess"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="do_guess();" value="Guess!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

php code (log.php):

```
<?php
    $dbh = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$dbh)  {
        die("Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error());
    }

    $db = mysql_select_db('test');

    if (!$db)  {
        die("Use database failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    $q = "INSERT INTO guesses (word, cnt) VALUES('" . $_GET["word"] . "', 1)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt=cnt+1";

    $r = mysql_query($q);
?>
```

database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `guesses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cnt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Hope that's enough

Comment: Ah thanks much, I am really sorry but I forgot to add that I want it to be saved to the server inside a simple database or CSV file

Comment: you want other users to see the mistakes other users did as well?

Comment: I just want to have access to it so that I can see that lots of people chose "word2" as the wrong word, and so on. To see how tricky each word is.

Comment: Look at my edit of the solution

Comment: WOW yes I think I can fully work with this. Thank you so much. I have a question and I've searched for about 10 minutes online to find the answer... where exactly is the database with the word values stored? Right now I'm using MAMP on my machine, and I can't for the life of me find where the table... goes. Thoughts? And thanks!

Comment: In other words, how can I view the results without creating an html file? Can't I browse it with a spreadsheet utility or something?

Comment: You need a mysql client to connect to your database and watch the data.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it now. Why exactly does the id start at 5? I guess the AUTO_INCREMENT field?

Comment: yeah because of my tests, I've auto-populated schools to the db.
prismspecs, if you find this answer satisfactory, please accept it as an answer.